# JAXB generation - How to enforce the presence of a nested element (-> inner class) in the Java code

Tags: jaxb, nested, inner-classes, lazy-initialization

I am using JAXB to generate domain objects from an XSD of our own devising. In the relevant fragment of the XSD, given below, I have a nested preProcessing element within the parent Job element. This gets resolved into a `PreProcessing` inner class within the parent `Job` class, as would be expected.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Job">
    <xsd:element name="preProcessing" nillable="false">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="mask" type="MaskTypeEnum" />
                <xsd:element name="userDefinedMaskFile" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="experimentalDesign" type="xsd:boolean" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

Accessing the inner class is done via a generated pair of get & set methods in the parent `Job` class, again as would be expected:

```
public Job.PreProcessing getPreProcessing() {
    return preProcessing;
}
public void setPreProcessing(Job.PreProcessing value) {
    this.preProcessing = value;
}
```

I'd like to be able to ensure that, in the Java code, there is always an instance of the `PreProcessing` class for an instance of `Job`. To this end, I would like to be able to customise the JAXB generation to either,

1) instantiate a `PreProcessing` instance in the `Job` class constructor
2) lazily instantiate a `PreProcessing` instance when the getter method is called (as happens for lists, which is nice)

The setter method would be redundant (and indeed, should not be called, since the `PreProcessing` instance is intended to be final).

I've Googled for JAXB + phrases such as lazy instantiation, default value, nested element and drawn a blank thus far. It seems that some class customisations can be carried out using custom XMLAdapters but my scenario isn't really related to the marshalling/unmarshalling, it relates to the manipulation of the domain objects in my Java application.